# Integrating JIRA to Maven: which URL?

Tags: maven, jira

I want to configure a maven project to use JIRA but I don't know which URL to use in the  element. I precise that I use an on-demand version of JIRA so I have an URL like https://company.atlassian.net/browse/CDR.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean the `<issueManagement>` element in the pom.xml as described here:
http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-model/maven.html#class_issueManagement

For example:

```
<project>
...
    <issueManagement>
        <system>jira</system>
        <url>https://company.atlassian.net/browse/CDR</url>
    </issueManagement>
...
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you think that's the good URL? I need a username/password to access JIRA, why Maven doesn't need them?

Comment: The issueManagement entry is just for informative purpose. It only describes where potential users can post bugs or feature requests for example. From what I know this information is only published on your maven site when you generate one.
What do you want to achieve or what are you expecting?

Comment: I expected that Maven can access JIRA to generate bug report for example and in this case, it needs information about how to connect. I've seen this in the Maven Changes plugin documentation.

Comment: Well then I think you have to provide the user and password as parameters to the goal `changes:jira-report` as described here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/jira-report-mojo.html